# unicode-math and tex4ht with utf-8 input

Tags: xetex, unicode, tex4ht, unicode-math, input-encodings

I have a document which I'm compiling to PDF using LuaTeX, and I want to create an HTML version from the same sources. The text is german with umlauts, and for convenience I'm using some unicode-math (also *hyperref* doesn't like `$\phi^2$` in the TOC but has no issue with `$φ²$`). Minimal example, compiles with `lualatex file`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
Löse $\sqrt{φ} = 1$
\end{document}
```

Now to compile it using `htlatex file "xhtml,mathml,charset=utf-8"` I add *inputenc* so it doesn't ignore the `ö`, but *unicode-math* isn't compatible with pdfTeX so I get an error for the `φ`, which can be ignored and is then missing from the output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
}{
    \usepackage{unicode-math}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Löse $\sqrt{φ} = 1$
\end{document}
```

So I use `htxelatex file "xhtml,mathml,charset=utf-8"`, without *inputenc* because XeTeX already expects UTF-8 input and does indeed complain when *inputenc* is used. However, now `ö` and `φ` are silently ignored in the output?! Compiling this code using `xelatex file` does give the expected result though, so it's a tex4ht problem.

And, I guess as a consequence of that, *unicode-math* doesn't work either, giving lots of errors which when ignored lead to no output at all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{
    %\usepackage{unicode-math}
}{
    \usepackage{unicode-math}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Löse $\sqrt{φ} = 1$
\end{document}
```

The unicode-specific options mentioned in the manual, i.e. `-cunihtf`, don't have any effect either… How do I make this work?

Or is that what the manual means by “partial support” for XeTeX (why does it work for pdfTeX then?!). The only reason I'm using XeTeX here is because there doesn't seem any LuaTeX-support for tex4ht, but could I maybe use LuaTeX to create the DVI for tex4ht anyway?

---

Things get weirder.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ö}{\"o}
\newunicodechar{φ}{\phi}
\begin{document}
Löse $\sqrt{φ} = 1$
\end{document}
```

Compiles with `htxelatex testhtml "xhtml,mathml,charset=utf-8"` and inserts `&#x03D5;` for `φ`, however the `ö` is inserted as a latin-1 encoded character. I have no idea where that comes from.

`htxelatex testhtml "xhtml,mathml,charset=latin-1"` only changes the charset in the header, the file is then displayed correctly.

Adding `" -cunicode -utf8"` as the third option causes the `φ` to be inserted as UTF-8, but doesn't change the latin-1 `ö`.

Comment: In [this thread](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex4ht/2013q1/000720.html) they use `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` or a script to replace each non-ascii character with a raw HTML entity, but I don't think this will work with *unicode-math* because it interprets i.e. `x²` as `x^2` which generates an `<msup>` etc. Also I thought XeTeX supported unicode directly?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with `tex4ht`, application which converts dvi file to html, doesn't support opentype fonts and compilation fails when one is used. Because it seems there is nobody who understand `tex4ht` c source and would be able to fix this bug, the only solution is to hack `unicode-math` to not use opentype fonts with `tex4ht`.

I hacked `fontspec` in similar way and it worked with texlive 2012, I am not sure about texlive 2013, since there was upgrade of many involved packages - [package code](https://github.com/michal-h21/fontspec) and [info page](http://michal-h21.github.io/fontspec/fontspec-4ht.html). I tried also to hack `unicode-math`, but I failed with that.

You can add some support with `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`, but it would fail in some cases, as you noted.

**Edit**
For your edited question, I can correctly compile your example, if I edit it little bit:

```
\documentclass{article}
\ifdefined\HCode
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ö}{\"o}
\newunicodechar{φ}{\phi}
\else
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}
\fi
\begin{document}
Löse $\sqrt{φ} = 1$
\end{document}
```

and compile with

```
htxelatex filename "xhtml, mathml, charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8"
```

Comment: Hm, I was hoping there was a stable solution, seems like I won't be able to avoid editing my document extensively for the tex4ht-edition